# Angular Facebook Share/Comments not showing

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook Share Button and the Comments in my application. This works perfectly on my local machine, but as soon as I upload it on the server the plugins are no longer shown. I'm using this directive to add the share button to the page:

```
angular.module('naturtripApp')
.directive('fbshare', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template: '<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="{{url}}" data-type="button_count"></div>'
    }
});
```

The url get's inserted in the $scope via:

```
$scope.url = $location.absUrl();
```

If I change the URL to static one, it's also working on the server.

The link to the app is http://naturtrip.org/#/view/353/52.5199-13.4386/20140526/751.

Any ideas?

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: nope. but i just managed to display at least the share button if I use this function in the directive to get the URL $scope.getLocation = function(){
            return document.location.href; 
        }

Comment: i'm still looking for some help! :(

Comment: you should create a fiddle